# An installer for shell scripts, written in pure sh

Tags: linux, unix, sh, installer

I wrote a tiny shell script that basically installs a script into your system by copying it to someplace like `/usr/local/bin`, chmodding it, and adding it to your PATH. It works on both Unix and Windows (via an emulation layer like MSys or Cygwin). Its source code is available [on GitHub](https://github.com/jamesqo/sinister). Here is the script in its entirety:

```
#!/bin/sh

set -e

help()
{
    echo 'sinister is a simple installer for shell scripts.'
    echo
    echo 'Usage: sinister -u url [options]'
    echo
    echo 'Options:'
    echo
    echo '-?,-h,--help: Print this help and exit.'
    echo '-c,--chmod: The mode to chmod your script. Defaults are a+x and u+x.'
    echo '-d,--debug: sinister should be run in debug mode.'
    echo '-l,--local: The script should be saved for the current user, instead of the entire machine.'
    echo '-n,--name: The name of the file the script should be saved to. Mandatory if no URL is given.'
    echo '-o,--output: The output directory the script should be saved to.'
    echo 'By default this is ~/bin on Unix systems, and C:\Users\you\AppData\Local\script on Windows.'
    echo '-u,--url: The location of the script online. e.g: https://github.com/you/repo/raw/master/script'
    echo 'If no URL is given the script is read from stdin.'
}

on_windows()
{
    uname | grep -q '[CYGWIN|MINGW|MSYS]'
}

per_user()
{
    test $LOCAL = 'true'
}

run_powershell()
{
    powershell -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass "$1"
}

getpath_windows()
{
    run_powershell "[Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable('PATH', '$1')"
}

setpath_windows()
{
    run_powershell "[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable('PATH', '$1', '$2')"
}

pwd_windows()
{
    run_powershell 'Get-Location'
}

CHMOD=
LOCAL='false'
NAME=
OUTPUT=
URL=

test $# -ne 0
while [ $# -gt 0 ]
do
    case "$1" in
        '-?'|-h|--help) help; exit 0 ;;
        -c|--chmod) CHMOD="$2"; shift ;;
        -d|--debug) set -x ;;
        -l|--local) LOCAL='true' ;;
        -n|--name) NAME="$2"; shift ;;
        -o|--output) OUTPUT="$2"; shift ;;
        -u|--url) URL="$2"; shift ;;
        *) help; exit 1 ;;
    esac
    shift
done

if [ -z "$CHMOD" ]; then
    if per_user; then
        CHMOD='u+x' # Executable for the current user
    else
        CHMOD='a+x' # Executable for all users
    fi
fi

if [ -z "$URL" ]; then
    test ! -z "$NAME"
    SCRIPT=$(< /dev/stdin) # read from standard input
else
    NAME=${URL##*/} # Grab everything after the last /
    if which curl > /dev/null 2>&1; then
        SCRIPT=$(curl -sSL "$URL")
    else # Assume wget is installed
        SCRIPT=$(wget -q -O - "$URL")
    fi
fi

if [ -z "$OUTPUT" ]; then
    if per_user; then
        if on_windows; then
            OUTPUT=~/AppData/Local/"$NAME"
        else
            OUTPUT=~/bin
        fi
    else
        if on_windows; then
            OUTPUT='/C/Program Files/$NAME'
        else
            OUTPUT='/usr/local/bin'
        fi
    fi
fi

# Use sudo on Unix
! on_windows && SUDO='sudo'

# Where the magic happens
$SUDO mkdir -p "$OUTPUT"
cd "$OUTPUT"
echo "$SCRIPT" | $SUDO tee "$NAME" > /dev/null
$SUDO chmod $CHMOD "$NAME"

# Add $OUTPUT to PATH if it's not in it
if ! which "$NAME" > /dev/null 2>&1; then
    if on_windows; then
        if per_user; then
            TARGET='User'
        else
            TARGET='Machine'
        fi
        CURRENT_PATH=$(getpath_windows $TARGET)
        CURRENT_DIRECTORY=$(pwd_windows)
        setpath_windows "$CURRENT_PATH;$CURRENT_DIRECTORY" $TARGET
    else # Unix
        CONTENTS="export PATH=\$PATH:$OUTPUT"
        if per_user; then
            echo "$CONTENTS" >> ~/.profile
        else
            sudo echo "$CONTENTS" >> /etc/profile
        fi
    fi
fi
```

Any feedback would be appreciated; I haven't tested this on Windows yet so some of the PowerShell snippets might be untested.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I see a number of things that may help you improve this program.  I don't have a Windows machine handy, so these will all be Linux-based observations.

### For local installation, don't use `sudo`

Right now, when the program is created for a local user, the use of `sudo` to copy it means it ends up owned by `root`.  That means that although it's in the local user's `bin`, they can't run it.  For local installation, `sudo` shouldn't be needed at all and would be a lot safer.

### Don't duplicate entries in `.profile`

Right now, each invocation of your program will cause an additional possibly duplicate line to be added to `.profile`.  Better would be to only add a line if it doesn't yet exist there.

### Use only POSIX features

Right now the code includes this line:

```
SCRIPT=$(< /dev/stdin) # read from standard input
```

However, that's not necessarily portable.  Instead, use `cat` as in:

```
SCRIPT=$(cat /dev/stdin) # read portably from standard input
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! I don't think I'm duplicating entries in `.profile` by the way, I do a check for `if ! which "$NAME"` before writing to it.

Comment: The check only looks at the current path rather tha the contents of the file. If the user hasn't re-run `.profile` between script invocations, the result is duplicate lines.

Answer (score 0):

It’s been some time since this question was posted but I thought I could add some useful feedback as the following issues are still present on the GitHub code.

### Testing for command availability

```
if which curl > /dev/null 2>&1; then
    SCRIPT=$(curl -sSL "$URL")
else # Assume wget is installed
    SCRIPT=$(wget -q -O - "$URL")
fi
```

While it will work on many systems, `which` isn’t recommended for checking if a command exists. See [Why not use “which”? What to use then?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/85249/why-not-use-which-what-to-use-then) for a full discussion.

`command -v` is most commonly recommended as a good alternative.  The `-v` flag was optional in the 2004 Edition but only became mandatory in the 2013 Edition of POSIX 2008.1.

I prefer to define the following function:

```
exists_command() {
  command -v "$1" >/dev/null 2>&1
}
```

Also, if I recall correctly, a base install of Cygwin had neither `wget` nor `curl` installed – though it did have `lynx` (this may have changed since I last looked). Accordingly, the [`apt-cyg`](https://github.com/transcode-open/apt-cyg) utility recommends using `lynx` to install it.

```
if exists_command curl; then
    SCRIPT=$(curl -sSL "$URL")
elif exists_command wget; then
    SCRIPT=$(wget -q -O - "$URL")
elif exists_command lynx; then
    SCRIPT=$(lynx -source "$URL")
else
    echo You need to install ‘curl’ or ‘wget’ to download URLs.
fi
```

### Output redirection and sudo

When using shell output redirection, the shell is running with the privileges of the user who started the shell. When the shell tries to open a file for writing, it can only do so if the user has permission to do so. In the the following code, only the `echo` command is run with super user privileges.

```
sudo echo "$CONTENTS" >> /etc/profile
```

To append content to a file, the output file needs to be opened with superuser privileges. A simple way to do that is to use the `tee` utility (with the `-a` flag to append to the file):

```
echo "$CONTENTS" | sudo tee -a /etc/profile
```